# Angular 2/4 : Reactive forms are synchronous while template-driven forms are asynchronous, How?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I was going through the doc of angular.io ([Reactive forms are synchronous](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#async-vs-sync)), trying to understand the reactive forms (how they are synchronous and template driven forms are asynchronous).

But the doc doesn't have enough explanation with example . Can anyone help me understand how template driven forms are asynchronous and reactive forms are synchronous?

I tried to explore a lot of blogs on the internet but didn't get an answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check the answer of mine. I have added the reference

Comment: Updated my answer , hope that helps you to understand , Basically directive you write in Template driven from makes difference

Answer (score 9):

Read this line careful in same documentation :

**Reactive forms are synchronous** (as you create controls from you code) 
In reactive forms, **you create the entire form control tree in code**. You can immediately update a value or drill down through the descendants of the parent form because all controls are always available.

**template-driven forms are asynchronous** (as it delegate task of creation of control)
Template-driven forms **delegate creation of their form controls to directives**. To avoid "changed after checked" errors, these directives take more than one cycle to build the entire control tree. That means you must wait a tick before manipulating any of the controls from within the component class.

---

In template driven from you write **[NgModel] or [NgForm] (directives)** that will take task of creation of your control on web page in html, that is how it becomes asynchronous.

If you attached hook **ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook** you will find difference between them easily ,

In Reactive forms you find control where in Template driven from you dont.

Comment: can you explain me with example

Comment: @shreyansh - in template driven from you write [NgModel] or [NgForm] that will take task of creation of your control on web page in html , that is how it becomes asynchronous ,

Comment: @shreyansh - f you attached hook ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook you will find difference between them easily ,

In Reactive forms you find control where in Template driven from you dont.

Comment: pranay - Thanks for your answer but I want to understand what is meant by line "You can immediately update a value or drill down through the descendants of the parent form because all controls are always available" and "To avoid changed after checked errors" , that is why I asked to explain with some example or any blog (link) is present on internet that clearly explains the difference.

Comment: @shreyansh - here : https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4