# asynchronous vs synchronous in angular form

Tags: angular

with the reference of angular official document **Reactive forms** are *synchronous* but **template driven forms** are *asynchronous*. What does it means?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665096/angular-2-4-reactive-forms-are-synchronous-while-template-driven-forms-are-asy

Comment: what you tried so far feel free to share your code so we will get the batter idea what went wrong

Comment: I do not have any code to show. My question is what is role of synchronous and asynchronous in angular form