# In unit test a form is reporting as valid, but not in regular environment

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a test that is failing because, in the test environment, a button is not disabled when it should be. I am able to reproduce this using this simple code:

```ts
<form #submissionForm="ngForm" novalidate>
<input
  type="text"
  ngModel
  required
  id="questionAnswer"
  name="questionAnswer"
>
{{ submissionForm.valid }}
<button [disabled]="!submissionForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Within the test, `submissionForm.valid` is `true`; however, in the running code it correctly reports as `false`.

Here is an example of the test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-mnbymr?file=app/app.component.html

And here is a running app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9uxvt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Note that I haven't added the `it()` in the stack blitz example - what I'd like to know is why is `valid` true in one app and `false` in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start off by saying that I don't *fully* understand what is actually going on here. Here is what I do know.

[Template-driven forms are *asynchronous*](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#key-differences). This can make testing a little bit tougher with template-driven forms because you have to take that factor into account (one of the reasons some people always prefer to use reactive forms). In my experience `fixture.whenStable()` has been helpful:

> fixture.whenStable()
>
> Get a promise that resolves when the fixture is stable.
> This can be used to resume testing after events have triggered asynchronous activity or asynchronous change detection.

Basically, you can put your code that tests the template-driven form inside of `fixture.whenStable().then()` and the form is guaranteed to be initialized and ready for interaction.

Here is an [updated stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-ohzkd7?file=app/app.component.spec.ts) with the test functioning correctly.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665096/angular-2-4-reactive-forms-are-synchronous-while-template-driven-forms-are-asy/49665237#49665237) is helpful to understand a bit more about what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  In practice I use `fixture.whenStable().then`; however, what your code has different is another call to `detectChanges` within the `then` - adding that fixed my issue.  Also, thanks for the links - that is something I didn't know.